# How to add json object as a type for attributes in sails-mongo

Tags: json, mongodb, sails.js, models, waterline

**Document.js**

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    type: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    createdBy: {
        model: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    comments: {
        model: 'Comments'
    },
    metaInfo: {
        type: 'json'
    }

 }
```

};

I would like to know if there is any way that I can write a model like the one given above, so that, I can add a json object to **metaInfo** which contains a name-value pair.

Eg:
json:
{  name: 'Project',  value: 'MyFirstProject'}

Is this possible through waterline?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you can! Exactly the way you have written above. This type allows you to store JSON objects as well as arrays

Answer (score 5):

I believe the comment answers your question. If you need any further help, you can refer the answers in this issue raised in Sails Github page: [JSON Array of Strings](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2396)